# Запятая в предложении "Нужно читать там где менее шумно"

Tags: пунктуация

> Нужно читать там где менее шумно

или

> нужно читать там, где менее шумно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) ***Нужно читать** там,* (2) *где **менее шумно**.*

Сравнить: Истина заканчивается там, где начинаются деньги.

Одинаковые предложения? В принципе да, это сложноподчиненные предложения (СПП) с придаточным места и местоименной связью где – когда, ГДЕ – союзное слово, ТАМ – указательное слово.

В сложном предложении ставится запятая, и здесь нет никаких причин, чтобы ее не ставить.

Тогда почему возникает вопрос о запятой? Я могу предположить, что автор вопроса затрудняется в определении двух предикативных основ (подлежащее + сказуемое).

Оба предложения односоставные безличные, в них можно выделить только сказуемое.

*Нужно читать* – составное глагольное сказуемое, модальная связка + основной глагол.

*Менее шумно* – составное именное сказуемое, связка "быть" в настоящем времени пропущена, именная часть выражена сравнительной степенью предикативного наречия "шумно".

Вот сколько информации надо знать школьнику, чтобы поставить запятую в сложном предложении.

А вот в предложении, приведенном для примера, основы определить несложно: *истина заканчивается* и *начинаются деньги*.